# How to correctly write if statement parsing a string to char, java

Tags: java, string, char, boolean

I am coding in java a boolean method to validate user input is correct. It is correct if the first thing typed is a letter A-D and the second thing typed is 1-4 (e.g. B3). When I set up my if statements I am getting an error next to them that say "The operator == is undefined for the argument type(s) char, boolean". I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. Here is the snippet of code.

```
public static boolean isValid(String s) {
    if (!isUpperCase(s)) {
        s = s.toUpperCase();
    }
    if (s.length() < 2) {
        if (s.charAt(0) == 'A' <= 'D') { // here is the first place I'm getting the error
            
            if (s.charAt(1) >= 1 <= 4) { // here is the second place I'm getting a similar error
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;   
}
```

Please excuse my ignorance as I am a novice coder and do not know all the terminology

Comment: You need to use a logical AND (&&) or OR (||) between your conditions, like `(s.charAt(0) <= 'A' && s.charAt(0) <= 'D')`

Comment: Or more likely, based on the explanation: `(s.charAt(0) >= 'A' && s.charAt(0) <= 'D')` and `(s.charAt(1) >= 1 && s.charAt(1) <= 4)`

Comment: Oh goodness, yes, you both figured it out! Thank you, that was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use String method `matches` which uses a regular expression:

```java
private static boolean isValid(String s) {
    return null != s && s.matches("(?i)[A-D][1-4]");
}
```

where
`(?i)` - enable case-insensitive matching
`[A-D][1-4]` - a single letter in range `[A..D]` followed by a single digit in range `[1..4]`

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify two variables or constants in an `if` statement.  You can connect pairs with logical operators like AND (&&) or OR (||).

You don't need to test if the String is upper case.  Converting it to upper case won't change anything if the letter is already in upper case.

Here's your method.

```
public static boolean isValid(String s) {
    if (s.length() < 2) {
        s = s.toUpperCase();
        if (s.charAt(0) >= 'A' && s.charAt(0) <= 'D') {
            if (s.charAt(1) >= '1' && s.charAt(1) <= '4') {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though there are two offered solutions right now, I didn't see any of them explaining why there's a problem. Thus I want to explain: The problem is the way you write your if statements. When you say `if (s.charAt(0) == 'A' <= 'D')`, the if feels like it is comparing a char and a boolean. Because 'A' <= 'D' is perceived as a true boolean statement.

With that said, you can use `&&` and check if your char is `char >= A && char <= D`